# how to join two tables using non primary key and remove duplicates in the result set

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am using MS Access 2013 DB
I have two tables
 **Table1:**
StartDate,EndDate, ID1, ID2,ProgramName, LanguageID,Language, Gender,CenterName,ZoneName 
**Table2**
StartDate,EndDate, ID3,ProgramName, LanguageID,Language, Gender,CenterName,ZoneName

I want to join these two tables and remove duplicates by comparing the following columns from both tables

StartDate,EndDate,ProgramName, LanguageID,Language, Gender,CenterName,ZoneName

some data in the columns StartDate, EndDate have null values also.
   The **resultant table** should contain the following columns with no duplicate data

StartDate,EndDate, ID1, ID2,ID3,ProgramName, LanguageID,Language, Gender,CenterName,ZoneName

Answer (score 0):

First you want create new table (other structer) 
Second insert every record to new table all record where value from table1 and table2 are diffrent (without duplicate). Remember about check

Comment: I have imported data(nearly 36,000 records) from excel and it has duplicates.